# submit form $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] whilst in jquery div show()

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a series of div style="display:none;" and im using jquery show hide for each div.

Inside one of the divs is a select menu, i want to submit the form to itself $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. How do i submit the form but still stay in the correct current div.

Thanks in advance.

```
   <div style="display:none;">
    <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post' name='form_filter' >
        <select id="employee_user" name="employee_user" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="">Select Staff</option>

    <?php  // $Id: emails.php, 27/06/2011 mbrennand
    $users_in_department = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT(employee) FROM holiday_entitlement_academic WHERE line_manager = \'' . $username. '\'');
    $users_in_department2 = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT(employee) FROM holiday_entitlement_business WHERE line_manager = \''.$username.'\'');

    while($user_in_dept = mysql_fetch_array($users_in_department)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$user_in_dept['employee'].'">'.$user_in_dept['employee'].'</option>';
    }
    while($user_in_dept2 = mysql_fetch_array($users_in_department2)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$user_in_dept2['employee'].'">'.$user_in_dept2['employee'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>    
    </select>
    </form>
    </div>


    <div style="display:none;">
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;">
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;">
    </div>
```

**EDIT....
CODE MODIFIED**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#employee_user').on('change', function(){
    $.post('SELF', $('form input,form select').serializeArray(), function(data){
         // Form has submitted
    });
});
</script>

<div style="float:right;">
<form action='' method='post' name='form_filter' >
    <select id="employee_user" name="employee_user">
    <option value="">Select Staff</option>

<?php  // $Id: emails.php, 27/06/2011 mbrennand
$users_in_department = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT(employee) FROM holiday_entitlement_academic WHERE line_manager = \'' . $username. '\'');
$users_in_department2 = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT(employee) FROM holiday_entitlement_business WHERE line_manager = \''.$username.'\'');

while($user_in_dept = mysql_fetch_array($users_in_department)) {
echo '<option value="'.$user_in_dept['employee'].'">'.$user_in_dept['employee'].'</option>';
}
while($user_in_dept2 = mysql_fetch_array($users_in_department2)) {
echo '<option value="'.$user_in_dept2['employee'].'">'.$user_in_dept2['employee'].'</option>';
}
?>    
</select>
</form>
</div>
<h2>STAFF HOLIDAY LEAVE</h2>
<br/>

<?php
$username_indept = $_POST["employee_user"];

$is_academic_result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM holiday_entitlement_academic WHERE employee = \'' . $username_indept . '\'');
$is_business_result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM holiday_entitlement_business WHERE employee = \'' . $username_indept . '\'');

if($is_academic = mysql_fetch_array($is_academic_result)) {
    switch($is_academic['units']) {
        case 'days':
            include_once('admin_academic_days.php');
            break;
        case 'hours':
            include_once('admin_academic_hours.php');
            break;
        default:
            break;
}
} else if ($is_business = mysql_fetch_array($is_business_result)) {
    switch($is_business['units']) {
        case 'days':
            include_once('admin_business_days.php');
            break;
        case 'hours':
            include_once('admin_business_hours.php');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} 
else {
         include_once('no_record.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"still stay in the correct current div."*?

Comment: Stay in the div that has the form in, the one that is shown.

Comment: submitting reloads a new page, you don't stay in anything

Comment: That was precisely the problem. Read the question, the others understand it.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to solve this issue:

- Use AJAX, in this case the page does not change and remains static in which case you stay in the right div.
- Use an iframe target which does the same as AJAX
- Use the form elements to understand how much of the form has been filled in and hide/show parts of the page dependant upon that.

Also as a tip don't use PHP_SELF in form submission. It is insecure.

An example of AJAX submit:

```
$('#employee_user').on('change', function(){
    $.post('SELF', $('form input,form select').serializeArray(), function(data){
         // Form has submitted
    });
});
```

Comment: please see my question. I have modified it with full code. It is not working, can you see any problems?

Comment: @Codded Yea my code was just an example it was not a copy and pasteable snippet. `SELF` needs to point to the page you wanna use.

Comment: @Codded i.e. PHP_SELF = 'mine.php' so 'SELF' will be 'mine.php'.

Comment: ok changed the SELF to the name of my page but still nothing. It dosnt seem to do anything, i am echoing $username_indept from my edited question. but nothing is returned. Any ideas

Comment: @Codded well it is kinda hard to say what is wrong without debugging the code and looking at what you got atm You need to look into the JQuery docs about AJAX and use the f12 console in your browser to debug the code.

Comment: ok i have found a solution here that seems to be working, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp Would you know how to change the function to jquery like yours?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15418/discussion-between-codded-and-sammaye)

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. submit forms by ajax
2. provide a pice of information in your request that will determine which div should be initially visible on page reload.

   This can be done via hidden input, action query parameter `action="?active_div=3"` or something similar.

Btw, if submitting to the current URL, you can leave the `action` atribute empty.